# Following recommended instructions fails to upgrade Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, 17.10, 17.04, do-release-upgrade

Please do not close as duplicate. I have followed the instructions in the other post: 
[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

I have also read the Wiki entries, which basically just say "update `sources.list`, update/`dist-upgrade`, and `do-release-upgrade`" just like the post.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/

It doesn't work; I get the following output:

```
Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-cublas-performance-update  InRelease                                               
Ign file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-cublas-performance-update  InRelease                                                 
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2  InRelease                                                                     
Ign file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2  InRelease                                                                       
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-cublas-performance-update  Release [574 B]                                         
Get:4 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2  Release [574 B]                                                               
Get:5 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-cublas-performance-update  Release [574 B]                                         
Get:6 file:/var/cuda-repo-8-0-local-ga2  Release [574 B]                                                               
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                                                               
Hit http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                  
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                              
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease                                                      
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease                                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                               
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease                                                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                 
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                              
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Updating repository information

Third party sources disabled 

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can 
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool 
or your package manager. 

To continue please press [ENTER]

.......

  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                 
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/universe arm64 Packages                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                 
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                 
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports/main arm64 Packages                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                 
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports/universe arm64 Packages                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                 
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main arm64 Packages                                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                 
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe arm64 Packages                                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                 
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse arm64 Packages                                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                 
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main arm64 Packages                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe arm64 Packages                                                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/multiverse arm64 Packages                                               
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main arm64 Packages                                             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/universe arm64 Packages                                         
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages                                       
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports/main arm64 Packages                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports/universe arm64 Packages                                       
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main arm64 Packages                                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe arm64 Packages                                        
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/multiverse arm64 Packages                                      
Fetched 466 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                           

Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

E:Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/main/binary-arm64/Packages 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80], E:Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80], E:Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80], E:Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80], E:Some index files failed to 
download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Sat Jan 27 17:47:46 2018) ===
```

Unfortunately, I can't copy the middle bits within the "......" because the upgrade process launches some sub-terminal process that doesn't allow scrollback (my normal Screen escape-and-scroll doesn't work, so who knows what this is?)

The problem seems to be that `us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` doesn't actually have artful archives?

Clarification added after some comments below:

- the problem seems to be that I added multi-arch support for arm64 to support cross compilation to Jetson TX2 (thanks!)
- this, in turn, doesn't work with automatic mirror selection, because many mirrors only mirror Intel architecture (why can't apt find an appropriate mirror?)
- suggestions to change the mirror used confuse me, because I can't find any documentation on how to convince `do-release-upgrade` to to use a particular mirror (I did use the Googles for 20 minutes; the closest I could come was how to point it at my own full archive mirror, which I neither know how to set up nor desire to set up)
- `do-release-upgrade` is specifically documented to swap out the sources.list file that exists on the system, meaning any local edits I do don't apply to the release upgrade

So, the question is now: How can I convince do-release-upgrade to use a specific mirror (or central archive) that has all the appropriate architectures?

Comment: I'd suggest dropping the 'us.' part of the 'archive.ubuntu.com' part; so instead of pointing to a mirror it points to the main site. Artful is there, but only for x86 (i386) and amd64 (x86_64). arm64 needs to point to main site only as its NOT mirrored. Either use the main site or add a limit to arch x86/x86_64  ... (ie. `deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://....`)

Comment: Again, sources.list is swapped out by do-release-upgrade, so I can't apply any changes to the sources.list that will be used by the new version. That's a main part of the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Most Ubuntu mirrors are of x86 (i386 arch) & x86_64 (amd64) only, and don't include the many other architectures like arm64. So you have two options

- use only the main mirror `archive.ubuntu.com/..`
- add a restriction to use only x86/x86_64 in the country.mirror

An example of the second option is

`deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful ....`

Comment: I see; the problem may be because I added multiarch for arm64 to support cross-development for the Jetson TX2 board.
Now, the problem is, that the new sources.list is downloaded by the do-release-upgrade script. How do I make that script do the appropriate restriction? AFAICT, do-release-upgrade doesn't use my original sources.list?

Comment: I also can't point /etc/update-manager/meta-release at archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: I would #comment out all arm64 references for the release- upgrade. Let your machine upgrade itself first, then add-them back in and dist-upgrade again.  Note: I've not used arm64 or a different arch outside x86 during release-upgrades so I've no experience.

Comment: @gulverc where would I #comment out arm64 references? These live inside the dpkg database.

Comment: I haven't used arm64, but I assume they'd be in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or one of the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/.  Your core [Ubuntu] x86 distro won't know about them so won't add them itself

Comment: As I stated in the post, the upgrade process swaps out any edited sources.list with a new copy that comes from the new version repository, which I cannot edit ahead of time. Also, swapping out sources.list (which is an apt configuration file) does not affect the set of installed architectures (which is a dpkg database thing.)

Comment: I know the install process uses sources outside the `sources.list` (for x86*) but I've never explored as to why; I'm guessing the release-upgrade does similar. I find it hard to believe it goes there for arm64 - but I don't know. The only thing I can think of is rebooting before release-upgrading (after removing x86 forcing re-read of files) but its a longshot...

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when trying to run `do-release-upgrade` on an actual `arm64` machine.

In the end, I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1003100/126244) to download the (in my case) `artful.tar.gz` upgrade package:

```
cd somewhere
curl -LO http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/artful.tar.gz
curl -LO http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/artful.tar.gz.gpg
gpg --verify artful.tar.gz.gpg artful.tar.gz
# this will fail, download the key:
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0x...
gpg --verify artful.tar.gz.gpg artful.tar.gz
tar xf artful.tar.gz
```

Then, remove everything from the `mirrors.cfg` file, and then only add:

```
http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/
```

Now, run

`./artful --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText`

to start the upgrade process.

I don't know how I ended up in this situation, it seems unlikely that `do-release-upgrade` shouldn't work on non-x86/x64 Ubuntu installations.